# How to resolve dynamic routes on client side in Next js framework

Tags: react-router, next.js, client-side, dynamic-routing

I am currently on Next js using full static generation, as I want to serve all my pages from the S3 + cloudfront (no server involved). Next js has good support for this except when it comes to dynamic pages (ex: /posts/:id). All the framework features to solve this type of scenario involve either rendering all passible pages at build time (which is not viable) or having a server to render these pages that have dynamic routes (making, therefore, the site an hybrid app).
To continue to be full static I need to have a way around this.
In create react app one could use the react-router and resolve the routes on the client side, which is exactly what I want to do for the dynamic routes. But I as far as I know next js and the react-router are not compatible, so apparently that is not an option.

Comment: did you find a solution or decided to fall back to ReactJS app with react routing? this is kind of stupid that NextJS docs don't cover this use case which I believe is pretty common

Comment: At that time, I went with Vercel instead of S3. So everything worked out of the box. But if you need the full static generation to deploy it somewhere else, I would say that the workaround is to use the dynamic part as a query param

Comment: And TBH, I don't think that this is necessarily NextJs fault. It really depends on which server you deploy your application. For instance, in S3 when you request something like your.domain.com/post/123, it will simply try to find the post/123.html in the bucket. There's no way to have it understand that it should search for the post.html and use 123 as a query param. You would need a proper customizable server for that

Comment: same, I just deploy to Vercel 

Comment: I think that's(deploying in vercel) the reason they don't specify properly in the documentation in a nice way how to achieve this. It is unfortunate that next is lacking a big feature that nuxt already has.

Comment: Check here very interesting what they suggest a huge COI to me https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-static-export#possible-ways-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I know, I think Dynamic Route on SSG is supported. Dynamic route feature is independent of `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. you can just use `next/router` to get the param you need and render your page accordingly.

Here is the official example.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```

---

**Reference**

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: this is not gonna work because on 1st render router.query will be undefined

Answer (score 5):

A solution (to work around this problem) would be to use query parameters and not path parameters

As a reminder, we have this type of architecture (of files).

```bash
pages/
├─ user/
│  ├─ [id].tsx
├─ index.tsx
├─ _app.tsx
```

And, we use `output: 'export'` in `next.config.js`.

The problem is that we cannot reach the /user/:id page in this configuration (only in CSR)

The solution is to add an `index.tsx` in this folder

```bash
pages/
├─ user/
│  ├─ [id].tsx
│  ├─ index.tsx  # NEW FILE HERE
├─ index.tsx
├─ _app.tsx
```

And the content of this `index.tsx` would be

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const UserHome = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.id) {
            router.push(`/user/${router.query.id}`);
        } else {
            router.push('/');
        }
    }, [router.query.id]);

    return <>Redirecting...</>;
};

export default UserHome;
```

To get easier URL-level access, use `trailingSlash: true` in your `next.config.js`. This will allow the use of `/user?id=abc` because in this case we get a 404 (or we have to add the `.html`) in the url...

In this sense, to access the page we use `/user?id=abc` which will redirect to `/user/abc`.

I am aware that this does not exactly answer the original problem.
But, for many cases (experiments), it works. That's why I'm sharing this here.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me as Next.js doesn't allow to use `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'` in the client-side component instead we need to use `import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'` and it did not provide `query`.
So to solve it you just need to catch {params} in your page like this

```
   export default function Page({ params.id }) {return <div>My Post{params}</div>;}
```

Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes